# How can I generate a diff from within Visual Studio for a codeplex project?

Tags: visual-studio, diff, patch

I made some changes  in the sourcecode for a project hosted on codeplex.
I'm not an author or editor on the project - just a user.
But I'd like to submit the changes as a patch.

Codeplex has a nice way to do upload the patch...

[image]

How can I generate a patch or a diff, from within Visual Studio?  How can I generate something that another VS developer could apply to update his source code?  **Does VS have a patch/diff capability?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [TFS command line tool, tf.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e(VS.80).aspx):

```
tf diff  <file>  | more
```

example output:

```
61,65c61
<
<             this.countdownDelay = (menuItem.Text == "none")
<                 ? 0
<                 : int.Parse(menuItem.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
<
---
>             this.countdownDelay = int.Parse(menuItem.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
136d131
<                 this.AddCountdownTimeMenuItem("none", parentItem);
```

Comment: You can also use the redirection operator to capture the diff, as in:  tf diff srcFile.cs > srcFile.cs.diff  . Also, I found that the diff output is "backwards". This is the expected result of TFS' reverse delta storage method. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/05/05/how-tfs-stores-files-and-calculated-deltas-on-versioned-files.aspx